# How to create a own theme in liferay 6.1.1 using Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, liferay, liferay-ide

I need to create a own theme for portal and it needs to be develop using Eclipsce Juno.
I have decide to customize the classic theme of liferay and i need to know the steps in it and files need to change for this.
Please advise and help in this

Comment: You can just start using [this tutorial](http://www.integratingstuff.com/2011/11/30/styling-liferay-creating-a-liferay-theme/), for example. Overall process didn't change much since then.

Answer (score 5):

Here are some steps which would help you become a theme developer:

1. You can download the latest [Liferay IDE](http://www.liferay.com/downloads/liferay-projects/liferay-ide) plugin for Eclipse Juno.
2. Then you can go through the [official documentation for creating themes](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/creating-liferay-them-7), which is concise and simple.
3. Customizing the classic theme is all about taking the various templates (`*.vm`) or css files from the Classic theme and including it in the `_diffs` folder of your custom theme. Here is the [source](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/tree/6.1.x/portal-web/docroot/html/themes).

Go through the official documentation and you will understand the (3) point.

In short I will include how to create a theme project:

1. Install Liferay IDE for your eclipse.
2. Restart Eclipse
3. After going through the steps given in this [wiki](http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Liferay+IDE+Getting+Started+Tutorial) or this [official documentation on Liferay IDE](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.0/development/-/ai/liferay-i-2).
4. File --> New --> Liferay Project --> Give project name --> Select Liferay Theme as the option
5. Click Finish
6. Wait for a few seconds and your theme project is ready with the required folder structure.
7. As you must be already knowing that Eclipse has a window where you can see `ant` commands, you can select the relevant ant commands to build and deploy the theme or create a WAR to be deployed on your server.
8. The official documentation will explain how to use the folders that are generated.

Also I would suggest you can checkout the different sample themes available [here](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-plugins/tree/6.1.x/themes)

Enjoy Themeing!!